# return statement has an error.. missing 1 required positional argument

Tags: python

I want to make bomb game with Queue.
but return statement has an error but I don't know what's wrong.... It's my code and error message please help.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oedma.png)
I'm trying to delete "players" until one person left.. and this person is winner of this game. So I return that person to variable "win" but it doesn't work...

```
import random


class ArrayQueue:
    DEFAULT_CAPACITY=10

    def __init__(self):
        self._data=[None]*ArrayQueue.DEFAULT_CAPACITY
        self._size=0
        self._front=0


    def __len__(self):
        return self._size


    def is_empty(self):
        return self._size==0

    def first(self):

        if self.is_empty():
            raise Empty("Queue is empty")
        return self._data[self._front]

    def dequeue(self):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Empty("Queue is empty")
        answer=self._data[self._front]
        self._data[self._front]=None
        self._front=(self._front+1)%len(self._data)
        self._size-=1
        return answer

    def enqueue(self, e):
        if self._size==len(self._data):
            self._resize(2*len(self.data))
        avail=(self._front+self._size)%len(self._data)
        self._data[avail]=e
        self._size+=1


    def _resize(self,cap):
        old=self._data
        self._data=[None]*cap
        walk=self._front
        for k in range(self._size):
            self._data[k]=old[walk]
            walk=(1+walk)%len(old)
        self._front=0

def hot_potato(self,players):
    pl=ArrayQueue
    for i in range(len(players)):
        pl.enqueue(players[i])
    rnum=random.randint(1,pl.__len__)

    while(True):
        bomb=pl.dequeue()
        if rnum!=0:
            pl.enqueue(bomb)
        else:
            bomb=None
            rnum=random.randint(1,p1.__len__)

        if p1.__len__==1:
            win=pl.dequeue()
            break
    return win      

players=["홍길동","홍동길","길홍동","길동홍","동홍길","동길홍","최정주","오소명","강그루"]
winner=hot_potato(players)
print(winner)
```

Comment: you've got `self` in your parameters, but the function is not a class member. Remove it, and see what happens

Comment: You defined `hot_potato()` to take two parameters but your only passing in one. You probably put `self` there by accident.

Comment: Thanks.. I removed self but it still not work.. TypeError: enqueue() missing 1 required positional argument: 'e'

Comment: That's a different syntax error ... and there's another after that ... please understand that we can't really work through every syntax and semantic error in this program.  You've written a *large* amount of code without bothering to test individual pieces.  I suggest that you back off, write a few lines at a time, and debug those before you add any more.  This is "incremental programming".

Comment: Thank you. you are right. I'll try your advice. Thank you guys!